# Артефакты и чёрные полосы в chrome и slack на ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, google-chrome, graphics

ubuntu 14.04 64-bit, chrome Версия 56.0.2924.76 (64-bit), постоянно дергается адресная строка и панель закладок (chrome)  и появляются артефакты (slack, chrome), в остальных приложениях вроде нормально. Началось это после того как я убрал видеокарту, хотел удалить драйвера с нее, но их нет, и комп использует нужную, интегрированую видеокарту. На ноутбуке без видеокарты нету таких проблем.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]